# Gradle with Eclipse - resources are not filtered

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-wtp

I have a gradle configuration setup to filter some resources and substitute properties depending on the environment (e.g. dev, production). These are located at:

- src/main/resources/config.xml
- WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

An example of a property from my web.xml file is below:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>server.url</param-name>
  <param-value>${server_url}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

An excerpt from my build.gradle is presented below:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

processResources {
  expand(props) // filter properties by environment
  exclude 'log4j.properties'
}

war {
    from 'WebContent'
    exclude('WEB-INF/web.xml')
    webInf {
        from 'WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml'
        expand(props)
    }
    webXml = null
}
```

This works fine when I build a war from the command-line, but when I use this configuration from Eclipse it does not seem to filter the resource appropriately.

I previously had the Maven plugin working where the resources would get filtered as a part of the Eclipse build. Is it possible to get Eclipse to filter the resources?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `webAppDirName`property for your project and remove the manuell stuff in `war { ... }` block. I am not sure which Gradle version introduced this property but at least 2.0. See also http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html.

Afterwards `gradle eclipse` should generate proper Eclipse artifacts to build your war or directly deploy to any server using wtp!